# Do business of software questions belong on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, business, marketing

Do questions revolving around some of the kinds of things Joel Spolsky sometimes discusses in his blog or Inc. articles have a place on Stack Overflow?

For example I mean subjects such as pricing strategy, business models, software as a service, venture capital, mobile applications markets, and so on.

If they don't belong here, does anybody have a suggestion of where to take such topics?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No. These are discussion topics - and [there's a place for that](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz).

Comment: Hadn't seen that link before...  Maybe that needs to be specifically called out for folks when asking subjective questions that are really discussion oriented...

Comment: @RSolberg: good point - i've added it to this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: @Shog9: can we get that entire thread added to official FAQ docs?   Simply put, it is great!

Comment: @Rsolberg: vote to migrate, if you have close votes - i'm out for the day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a good option for a StackExchange site?  There have been quite a few questions coming up on trying to define what is programming related and what is not. What is computer related and what is not...

Hopefully a good definition for those is created so it's easy to point to a FAQ about it...

Answer (score 0):

Not on stack overflow but perhaps as another "stackexchange" site ... and I suggested (but got no comments or votes) in the question "What StackExchange sites do you want to see" (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/what-stackexchange-sites-do-you-want-to-see/7525#7525)